# Removing double quote with Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework-6

I'm working in a legacy code which uses EF 6.0 with SQL Server. Now, the company got a new client that is using Oracle, and all the tables were created using quotes `CREATE TABLE "AAA"` (which forces me to write all queries using "AAA"), and I'm having some issues about this.

I researched that if I remove the double quotes from the query, works fine. There are some way to configure the EF6.0 to always remove double quotes before send the request to database?

Comment: Look at custom code-first conventions.

Comment: So, I have to change all entities to adapt to conventions? There are no way to just configure EF 6.0 to remove double-quotes?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819164(v=vs.113).aspx, esp. "modelBuilder.Types()"

Comment: Nice! This helps a lot. But I still having some tables written "AAA" and "Aaa", so I can't  change to upper case all, for example. But your tip will helps me for now. 

Thanks.